# How do we unit test this lambda expression?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

We have a REST end point (JAX-RS) that is invoked from the browser. We are passing around OutputStream so that we could have the browser display the result of the call.

Here is the method.

```
@Path("/mypath/{userId}")
@POST
public Response createUser(@PathParam("userId") final int userId ) {
    StreamingOutput stream = (outputStream) -> {
        User user = userHelper.findUser(userId);
        userHelper.updateUser(user,outputStream);
    };

    return Response.ok(stream).build();
}
```

**Using Junit and Mockito, how do we verify if `userHelper.findUser` and `userHelper.updateUser` has been called** ?

Basically we just want to verify the interactions.

Comment: You have to inject a Mock of userHelper. Have you created a TestCase already?

Comment: Yes. That doesn't work. Interaction doesn't happen because it is a lambda expression.

Comment: so your test should trigger interaction and then verify a mock

Answer (score 2):

To "unit" test this you should create your test class and create a new instance of the class this method belongs to in the test class. The userHelper is not defined in the lambda so it is a class member? If so it can be mocked:

- Create a [mock](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#creating-and-configuring-mock-objects-with-mockito) userhelper object with Mockito
- [inject](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#mockito_dependencyinjection) the mock to your test class.
- Call the createUser method.
- [verify](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#mockito_verify) on the mock to assert the updateUser method is called once.
- You can go a step further and verify what user and outputStream objects are passed using [captors](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#capturing-the-arguments).

Answer (score 0):

The StreamingOutput is only called when somebody on the other end (typically the browser) start pulling from it. You test case will need to take over and (as suggested by the comments) start interaction with the Response.